# Put "read" line back in file

Tags: c++

I am wondering if it is possible to put a line back in a file if it has been read in.
Here is a sample of what I am doing:

```
string templine;
while(templine.at(0)!=">"){
getline(file,templine);
//do some stuff with string
}
```

So basically I want to keep reading in the file until the first character of the next line is ">". The amount of lines between each ">" is inconsistent. The way I am reading it in now it will read the next line with a ">" but I dont want to actually do anything with that line yet and want to "put it back" in the file so I can read it again later. I am working in C++ VS10

My files look something like

">"2013 11 24 //The date, had to put > in " "

1 2 3 4

5 6 7 8

">"2013 11 25

1 2 3 4

">"2013 11 26 etc...

Comment: you want to *read it later*, why not read it and store it, anyway you want to read it?

Comment: gongzhitaao's suggestion makes more sense. Regardless, merely complementary is my suggestion: `fstream` inherits the method [putback](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/putback/) which seems to allow you to *put back* a single character. But I'm not sure. If that doesn't work, try the [tellg](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/tellg/) and [seekg](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/seekg/) methods. That should introduce you to how files are actually read.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```
while(file.peek() != '>'){
    std::getline(file,templine);
    //Do work
}
```

where file is your `ifstream`. That way, you will not read the line with > until you need it.

Comment: for more recent c++ standards, prefer `static_cast<char>` instead of `char{}`